# undefined control sequence in my code

Tags: errors

I am getting undefined control sequence from this code.

```
$\begin{align}\nonumber 
        \ul{F}^k(X,1) := \left\{ \mathlarger{\sum}_i (\sigma_i, \|\ \|_L, Z_i) : \begin{align} codim_X Z_i = k -1,\\ (L_i/Z_i, \|\ \|_L) \ numeric ,\\
    \sigma \in Rat^*(L_i), \\
    \mathlarger{\sum} \ div(\sigma_i) = 0
     \end{align} \ \ \ \right\}
    \end{align}$
```

I would like for the code to look like this once compiled. I have been trying to hunt for the error for hours.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is incomplete, hence it's unclear which control sequence is undefined. Nevertheless, here is a complete working example, in which

- The outer `align` environment along with `\nonumber` is replaced with unnumbered `align*` env, and the inner `align` env is replaced with `aligned` env.
- The `$ ... $` surrounding outer `align` env is removed.
- Operators like `Rat` and text (`numeric`) are both typeset in upright font shape marked, using appropriate markup commands. You may also interested in `amsmath` command `\DeclareMathOperator`.
- `soul`'s text mode command `\ul` is replaced with math mode command `\underline`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \underline{F}^k(X,1) := 
  \left\{
    \mathlarger{\sum}_i (\sigma_i, \|\ \|_L, Z_i) : 
    \begin{aligned}
      \operatorname{codim}_X Z_i = k -1,\\
      (L_i/Z_i, \|\ \|_L) \text{ numeric}, \\
      \sigma \in \operatorname{Rat}^*(L_i), \\
      \mathlarger{\sum} \operatorname{div}(\sigma_i) = 0
    \end{aligned} \ \ \ 
  \right\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. There's no need for an (internally fairly elaborate) `align*` environment, though. `\[ ... \]` will do as well -- better, in fact, because it's simpler. I would also question the use of `\mathlarger`, as there appears to be no need to enlarge the summation symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `align` and definitely cannot have `align` inside inline math mode (that is inside `$...$`).

The error message I get is

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{align} allowed only in paragraph mode.
```

A more correct input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\codim}{codim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rat}{Rat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} % divergence, \div is already used

\begin{document}

\[
\underline{F}^k(X,1) :=
\left\{
  \sum_i (\sigma_i, \|\ \|_L, Z_i) :
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% local setting
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \codim_X Z_i = k -1,\\
  (L_i/Z_i, \|\ \|_L) \text{ numeric},\\
  \sigma \in \Rat^*(L_i), \\
  \displaystyle\sum_i \Div(\sigma_i) = 0
  \end{array}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]